# ng2-auto-complete works differently on the timeout function

Tags: angular, api, typescript

`ng2-auto-complete` works differently in the timeout function in the Angular and Typescript. The `setTimeout()` function is required because it needed to retrieve data from the API. If we call the function on `ngOninit` works differently in timeout and non timeout conditions.

We try to set a value for auto complete textbox. Without any timeout function autocomplete works as per the expected. But it takes little time to get data from API. So we use small timeout. We get the data but its bind and show as below. Please correct me if I did anything wrong and suggest me a solution

```
[object Object]
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FAlPL99RogKaGtlAjDPZ?p=preview)

Comment: You shouldn't really use a setTimeout, what happens if the network is particularly slow and the data comes after the callback has been executed? If the data comes from an API, just subscribe to the call and set your properties inside the subscribe

Comment: create a service that returns Observable from the API call subscribe to that call .. set the data for the autocomplete in the success handler

Comment: I tried with subscribe but still it showing the same. http://plnkr.co/edit/dp0aFKzNZkAu27eZ7c0u?p=info

Comment: You get an object displayed because you set the formcontrol value to an object. If you want to have a string then set the value to a string `this.continent = new FormControl(entry.name);`